# Proving an affine set's equivalence to the solution set of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I am stuck with the following equivalence about Affine Sets: "$L$ being an affine set is equivalent to $L$ being the solution set of a set of equations $Ax=b$ for some $A,b$."

In a more mathematical statement:

$L$ is an affine set $\iff$ $L=\left\{x|Ax=b\right\}$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for some matrix $A$ and $b$.

Proving that $L=\left\{x|Ax=b\right\}$ implies an affine set is easy, I pick $x,y \in L$. Then using the definition of affinity, such that $\alpha x + \beta y \in L$ with $\alpha + \beta = 1$, it is $A(\alpha x + \beta y)=\alpha A x + \beta A y=b$.

Proving the other direction of the equivalence is where I run into trouble. I have the definition of $L$ with $(\alpha x + \beta y) \in L$ where $\alpha + \beta =1$ and $x,y \in L$. But I don't see how I can use this to reach $L=\left\{x|Ax=b\right\}$ to begin with. How should I go on from here?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Take any vector $v\in L$ and show that the set $$\{x-v| x\in L\}$$ is a linear subspace.

Comment: $v$ should be fixed, once we picked it, right?

Comment: Yes. For every $v$, the set $L_v = \{x-v| x\in L\}$ is a linear subspace, and $L=v+L_v$, so if you can just find a matrix such that $L_v$ is its kernel, you are done.